# How to clear ckeditor value when another row of data is selected?

Tags: modal-dialog, ckeditor

I have a modal form containing a ckeditor. I use this modal form to fetch data in table. when i open first row of data, ckeditor shows the content but when i open another row of data in the same table, the ckeditor does not show the content of the selected row which means it only show the first selected row.

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-modal-announcement', function() {
            $('.modal-title').text('Announcement');
            $('#sid').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#sannounce_to').val($(this).data('announce_to'));
            $('#sannounce_from').val($(this).data('announce_from'));
            $('#sannounce_cat').val($(this).data('announce_cat'));
            $('#sannounce_subject').val($(this).data('announce_subject'));
            $('#smessage').val($(this).data('message'));
            $('#screated_user_id').val($(this).data('created_user_id'));
            $('#screated_user_email').val($(this).data('created_user_email'));
            $('#screated_at').val($(this).data('created_at'));
            id = $('#sid').val();
              $(function () {
                  CKEDITOR.replace('smessage')
                  $('.textarea').wysihtml5()
                });
              CKupdate();
            $('#showModalAnnounce').modal('show');
        });
```

Comment: Are you using same code for each row (is same editor created for same element with same id)? If yes, do you destroy old editor before creating it for new row? If not, this is probably the problem. You can't create more than one editor on a single element. You can either create/destroy instances https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/saveajax.html or update existing ones with new data - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData

Comment: No data for other fileds changes execpt for the data in the ckeditor. If i remove ckeditor and remain it as a textarea, the data is fetched. I think my problem here is on how to dispose the old content of the ckeditor.

Comment: In order to set/change editor data you need to use `setData` method https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData but if you are using jQuery, you need a jQuery adapter and `val` method. Please see: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/samples/old/jquery.html and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters_jQuery.html.